# How to add database to pervasive sql Control Center?

Tags: pervasive-sql

[image]I've never touched PervasiveSql before and now I have a bunch of .ddf and .Btr files. I read that all I had to do was create a new database in the control center and point to the folder that contains these files.
When I do this and look at the database there is nothing in it. Since I am new to Pervasive, I'm more than likely sure that I'm doing something wrong.

EDIT: Added a screen shot after running command prompt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create a database name in the PCC, you need to connect to the engine then right click the engine name and select **New** then **Database**.  Once you do that, the following dialog should be displayed:
[image: Create Database Dialog]

Enter the database name, and path.  The path being where the DDFs are located.  In most cases the default options are sufficient.

A longer process is documented at [http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=uguide/using.02.5.html.](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=uguide/using.02.5.html)

If you pointed to a directory that had DDF files (FILE.DDF, FIELD.DDF,and INDEX.DDF) when you created the database name, you should see tables listed. 
If you pointed to a directory that does not have DDF files, the database will still be created but will have no tables defined. You'll either need to get DDFs from the vendor or create the table entries using CREATE TABLE (with IN DICTIONARY clauses) or use DDF BUilder to add table entries.

Based on your screen shot, you only have 10 records in FILE.DDF.  This is not enough.  There are minimum system tables  required (X$FILE, X$FIELD, X$INDEX, and a few others).  It appears your DDFs are not a valid set.  Contact the client / vendor that provided the DDFs and ask for a set that include all of the table definitions.

Once you have tables listed in your Database Name, you can use ODBC to access the data.

Comment: That was what the first thing that I did, I read the same instructions as you provided. But nothing wants to appear.

Comment: After I add everything the way its supposed to and when I open the database and look at the tables and there are no tables. The tables folder is empty.

Comment: I have both the ddf and btr files. I'm not sure if its the complete database. Or does that matter?

Comment: Where did the DDFs come from?  Did they come from a vendor or were they created when you create the database name?

Comment: The files came from a client of mine. He sent the btr and ddf files. He gave the same instructions that you gave, but nothing happened. I'm not sure whether he sent the complete database, it could be partial and I'm not sure if that matters?

Comment: The DDF files store the table / field / index information so that the BTR (in this case) files can be access through ODBC or other access methods.  If the DDFs don't have tables defined, they won't help.  From a command prompt, run "BUTIL -STAT FILE.DDF" in the directory where the DDFs are located.  It'll give, among other information, the number of records.  If it's 13 or less, you might have an invalid DDF set. Ask the client where he got them.

Comment: I'm going to try out your suggestion and contact my client again to see if I have everything I need. Thanks for sticking through with me on this, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I edited my question and added a screen shot of what was shown after I ran your suggestion...

Comment: I've edited my answer to include information about your screenshot.

Comment: Thank you. I've contacted my client and he is going to log in via team viewer and set it up. Thanks again for your help, I appreciate it.